# iOS static table cell border is behind text view

Tags: ios

When adding a textview directly below a table cell xcode removes the last border. how exactly do you get that back?

[image: simulator]

[image: layout]

Comment: You could add constrains to make the text view a bit smaller as the cell. One point in each direction should work.

Comment: thanks for the response and seemed to get me going in the right direction although the solution is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bit of a hack, but adding an extra cell with 1px height seems to do the trick.

Comment: This is not what I recommended. I meant to put the text view away from the cell edges.